# javascript sorting 2D array makes duplicates in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort my 2D array according to column 3.
when I sort it with sort function, all the array members become duplicates of one member of the original array.

so for example;

my original array:

```
[12, AAA, eee, 5]
[58, BBB, zzz, 3]
[28, CCC, ddd, 6]
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
```

I want it  to become :

```
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
[28, CCC, ddd, 6]
[12, AAA, eee, 5]
[58, BBB, zzz, 3]
```

I use the code :

```
function sortByColumn(a, colIndex){

    a.sort(sortFunctionq);

    function sortFunctionq(a, b) {
        if (a[colIndex] === b[colIndex]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return (a[colIndex] > b[colIndex]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

var sorted_a = new Array(15);
sorted_a = sortByColumn(arr, 3);
```

now the array becomes:

```
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
[18, DDD, fff, 9]
```

I am using javascript on Samsung Gear watch. maybe it does not support the "sort" function correctly.
is there a way to sort 2D array without using sort function ?

---

final code is:

```
    var sorted_a = new Array(15);
    sorted_a = sortByColumn(arrx, 3);
    arrx= sorted_a;

function bubbleSort(a, fCompare) {
    if( a.length < 2)   {return a;}
    for( var length = a.length-1; length; --length) {
        var noSwaps = true;
        var temp;
        for(var c=0; c<length; ++c) {
            if( fCompare( a[c], a[c+1]) > 0) {
                temp = a[c+1];
                a[c+1] = a[c];
                a[c] = temp;
                noSwaps = false;
            }
        }
        if( noSwaps) {break;}
    }
}

function sortByColumn(a, colIndex){
    function sortFunctionq(a, b) {
        if (a[colIndex] === b[colIndex]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return (a[colIndex] > b[colIndex]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    //return bubbleSort(a, sortFunctionq);
    return bubbleSort(a.slice(), sortFunctionq);
}
```

but now nothing is available in the array.

for those who ask:
if I remove the sort function and use arrx as it is, I can reach 2D array elements with arrx[1][1]
but with the code above arrx[1][1] returns null.

---

I changed it a bit and now it seems to work.
But now I need to remove duplicates as well.  How can I do that ?

current code:

```
    var arrx = new Array(50);
    for (var j = 0; j<50; j++){
        arrx[j] = arr[j].split("|+");
    }
    var arry = new Array(50);
    arry = bubbleSort(arrx);

function bubbleSort(a) {
    for( var r = 49; r >= 0; --r) {
        var noSwaps = true;
        var temp = new Array(50);
        for(var c=0; c<r; ++c) {
            if (a[c][3] < a[c+1][3]) {
                temp = a[c+1];
                a[c+1] = a[c];
                a[c] = temp;
                noSwaps = false;
            }
        }
        if( noSwaps) {break;}
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I saw that your code run correctly. Can you provide jsFiddle to show the exactly result.

Comment: Or better still, a code snippet in the question that when run produces the correct result (in a browser)

Comment: I see your code is working perfectly in console. Can you verify your input "arr"

Comment: The code shown does not produce the results shown - maybe something is going wrong somewhere in code *not* shown in the question? You don't show how the array is created or how you try to use it after sorting. As an aside, the `sorted_a = new Array(15)` line is pointless because on the next line you assign a completely unrelated value to the `sorted_a` variable, so the empty array gets thrown away. Also, the `.sort()` function sorts the array *in place*, i.e., it changes the original array, so your `sorted_a` and `arr` variables both end up referring to the same array.

Comment: My wild guess is that you are not initializing your array to be sorted properly in the first place. Please console log the array before sorting and see if there are duplicates already.

Comment: Omit the initialization of `temp` and leave it declared as `var temp;`  `temp` is a temporary variable used when swapping  the values of `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` and is set before reading it back. Initializing it to anything is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to you question is "yes, it is possible to sort an array without using the array's sort method".  A simple example using bubble sort:

```js
function bubbleSort(a, fCompare) {
    if( a.length < 2)
        return a;
    for( var length = a.length-1; length; --length) {
        var noSwaps = true;
        var temp;
        for( i=0; i<length; ++i) {
            if( fCompare( a[i], a[i+1]) > 0) {
                temp = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
                noSwaps = false;
            }
        }
        if( noSwaps)
            break;
    }
}

function sortByColumn(a, colIndex){
    function sortFunctionq(a, b) {
        if (a[colIndex] === b[colIndex]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return (a[colIndex] > b[colIndex]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    return bubbleSort(a, sortFunctionq);
}
var a = [
   [12, 'AAA', 'eee', 5],
   [58, 'BBB', 'zzz', 3],
   [28, 'CCC', 'ddd', 6],
   [18, 'DDD', 'fff', 9],
];
 
var sortedA = sortByColumn(a,2)  // updates a in-place, as well
console.log( JSON.stringify(sortedA))
```

### However

Note that both the `sort` method of an array and the `bubbleSort` above change the order of elements in the array being sorted, without creating a shallow copy of the array. While `bubbleSort` may show the Samsung JS engine has a problem, more than likely it will not and produce the same result.

Because sorting sorts the array in place, you may wish to check if creating a shallow copy of it before sorting solves the problem. EG by replacing the return statement in the example with

```
return a.slice().sort(functionq) // OR
return bubbleSort(a.slice(), functionq)
```

---

#### Debugging notes:

1. JavaScript arrays are objects. The value of an object variable is a reference of some kind used by the JavaScript engine to access object properties. The reference could be a memory pointer or some other value used by the engine to access object data. When you assign an object to a variable, its existing content is overwritten. If you assign the same object value to two variables, they hold the same refernce value and refer to the same set of object data.

   ```
   var arry = new Array(50);
   arry = bubbleSort(arrx);
   ```

   unnecessarily creates a new Array, because the new Array value is overwritten in the second line.  It can be simplified as

   ```
   var arry = bubbleSort( arrx).
   ```

   Note that JavaScript arrays can grow and shrink and do not have some pre-allocated length.
2. Both the bubble sort code and the inbuilt array `sort` method (inherited by an array instance from the `Array.prototype` object, and documented on MDN under [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) sort the array in place and return an object reference to the array being sorted. After

   ```
   arry = bubbleSort(arrx);  // OR
   arry = arrx.sort(sortFunction)
   ```

   **the value of `arry` is the same as `arrx`.** If you want to make a copy of the array that is immune to `arrx` modificatioms of first dimension values, make a shallow copy of the input array before sorting:

   ```
   arry = bubbleSort(arrx.slice());
   ```

   If you want to make a copy that is immune to modifications to either dimension value then make a shallow copy of both dimensions' arrays as for example:

   ```
   arry = bubbleSort( arrx.map(element => element.slice())
   ```

   This creates new arrays from both dimensions of `arrx` before sorting.

If you are still getting duplicate entries after this you will need to find out where in the code the duplicates are being assigned.

---

### Tip

Check there are no typos in conditional tests that use `=` (the assignment operator) instead of `==` or `===` operators to test for equality. This is a good way of inadvertently assigning values to something that was not meant to be changed.

Comment: ok. I tried both but it does not work. the new array is not showing anything. I will update the initial post so that you could check what I am doing wrong. The watch screen is very small so I can not do much troubleshooting. How can I find out where the error is ?

Comment: Traktor53,  what can I try ?

Comment: sorting is ok now. how can I remove duplicates ?

Answer (score -2):

All you need to change is to return the **sorted** array.

```js
const data = [
  [12, 'AAA', 'eee', 5],
  [58, 'BBB', 'zzz', 3],
  [28, 'CCC', 'ddd', 6],
  [18, 'DDD', 'fff', 9]
];

function sortByColumn(a, colIndex){
    function sortFunctionq(a, b) {
        if (a[colIndex] === b[colIndex]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return (a[colIndex] > b[colIndex]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    return a.sort(sortFunctionq);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}


const result = sortByColumn(data, 3);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the OP uses `Array.prototype.sort`. This does not add anything new.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts an array in place, and returns the array it was called on. The code in the question works as expected in a browser.

Comment: *"it always returns a new array"* - The opposite is true.

Comment: so why doesn't it work with my situation ? is it a wrong implementation ? what can I do ?

Comment: and now what can I do ?

Comment: I didn't try as people said it won't work. but I can try if you insist ?